# how can i Select from a select list that enabling select list 2 by watin in c#

Tags: c#, list, select, watin, selectlist

i have a problem in controlling web page by watin...
we have a html page with 2 select list that when you select an item from selectlist1 , selectlist2 will be visibled ... 
but when i select a value from select list 1 by watin , it wont be visibled...why?

i use this code for selectlist1:

```
br.SelectList(Find.ByName("Selectlist1[year]")).Focus();
br.SelectList(Find.ByName("Selectlist1[year]")).SelectByValue("2015");
```

now selectlist2[day] must be visibled....but nothing....

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to do. Update your question with more detail, along with current output and desired output

Comment: I've actually run into this issue before. Do you own the web page? If so you could add a js function to show the second select list and trigger that with watin.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you own/have control over the html page, you could add a js function to show the second select list and trigger that with Watin. Something similar to this:

```
br.SelectList(Find.ByName("Selectlist1[year]")).Focus();
br.SelectList(Find.ByName("Selectlist1[year]")).SelectByValue("2015");
br.DomContainer.Eval("ShowNextList()");
```